# How should I store an array in redis?

Tags: node.js, npm, redis

I have a query that returns an array of objects in javaScript (`json`) and I need to save it in `redis` without the need for a `foreach`,

I currently use the `redis` `set` command and converted the `json` array to `string`, but I don't know how optimal this is since we are talking about a `json` array converted to `string`.

This is the code you use to try to emulate the array storage of `json` objects in`redis`.

```
client.set('proyectos',JSON.stringify(proyectos));
 res.json(proyectos);
```

Here I extract the chain and convert it back into an array of `json` objects.

```
redisCtrl.getProyectos=async (req,res,next)=>{
   client.get('proyectos').then(proyectos=>{ 
       if(proyectos){
          console.log("ok"); 
          res.json(JSON.parse(proyectos)); 
        }
        else
          next();
   }).catch(err=>{
       console.error("error"); 
       next();
   });
};
```

This returns the following:

`[{"id":1,"nombre":"cualquier","descripcion":"descripción muy especifica","monto":"100000","fecha":"2019-10-16","estado":true},{"id":2,"nombre":"conjunto autosustentable","descripcion":"es un proyecto creado para favorecer al medio ambiente y reducir costos de estilo de vida","monto":"15000","fecha":"2019-12-16","estado":true},{"id":3,"nombre":"cultivo autosustentable","descripcion":"el objetivo es reducir el costo de producción de alimento y favorecer el medio ambiente","monto":"190000000","fecha":"2019-12-16","estado":true}]`

This in itself is not a mistake, but I would think it is a bad practice as mentioned above, and more for a mass production environment, so how should I do this in the most optimal way possible?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow.  Este website esta usando solamente Ingles, no Español.  Please use English.

Comment: Did you consider using RedisJSON?

Comment: I am new to redis, I did not know that there is redisJSON thank you very much

Comment: What dependency or npm module should I use for json arrays?

Answer (score 1):

if your object are shallow, you can use hash for each item and a list for the array

using a list key for name of the item keys `itemlist`
using hash for storing actual data in key such as `item:1`

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nombre: 'cualquier',
        descripcion: 'descripción muy especifica',
        monto: '100000',
        fecha: '2019-10-16',
        estado: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nombre: 'conjunto autosustentable',
        descripcion:
            'es un proyecto creado para favorecer al medio ambiente y reducir costos de estilo de vida',
        monto: '15000',
        fecha: '2019-12-16',
        estado: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        nombre: 'cultivo autosustentable',
        descripcion:
            'el objetivo es reducir el costo de producción de alimento y favorecer el medio ambiente',
        monto: '190000000',
        fecha: '2019-12-16',
        estado: true
    }
]

// using ioredis lib in this example
// saving it to redis

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = data[i]
    await redis.hmset('item:${item.id}', item)
    await redis.lpush('itemlist', `item:${item.id}`)
}

// getting it back from redis: first geet the keys ; then get all the data
const keys = await redis.lrange('itemlist', 0, -1) // 0, -1 => all items

const p = redis.pipeline()
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];
    p.hgetall(key)
}
const resp = await p.exec()
```

Comment: Is this serious optimal for an international web development?, why the idea would be to use this in case a user who logs in consults his shopping cart or his list of paid or unpaid or mixed invoices through redis, 
What worries me is that this overloads the cache if there are miles of honey from users who do this at the same time