# Store objects with an id as key in redis with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I want to store objects in redis in node js

So far I have tried this:

```
redisClient.setex(item._id, 3600, temp, (err, data) => {    
    if (err) {    
        reject(err);
    } else {
        resolve(data)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.setex()` is for string. what you're passing there is object. if you want to use string data type in redis, you will have to pass a String to it by `JSON.stringify(temp)` and `JSON.parse` when you get it back from redis.

```js
redisClient.setex(item._id, 3600, JSON.stringify(temp), (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        reject(err)
    } else {
        resolve(data)
    }
})
```

redis has a data type that is similar to object which is [hash](https://redis.io/commands#hash) but this only works if your object is shallow.

```js
redis.hmset('item:${item._id}', item) // saving
redis.hgetall('item:1') // geting all fiellds out
redis.hmget('item:1', ['field1', 'field2']) // geting some fields out
```

usage is different for each library but the idea is like this

[image]

Comment: i want to store object not strings how can i do that?

Comment: @BasirBaig update the answer. you can use hash for that purpose

Comment: can you show me how we can do with that?as i am new to reddis.Thanks

Comment: what is meant by shaalow please

Comment: id:{name:"abc","price":"12"} i have to make these kind of object with different ids.Thanks

Comment: shallow means it's not deep. it's nested only 1 level `{id: 1, name "test"}` is shallow.  but this `{id:1, data: [{id: 1, name: 'test'}]}` is not

Comment: Thankyou for your help and I want to ask can I store array of objects agains a key?

Comment: "_id":[{id: 1, name: 'tes1t'},{id: 2, name: 'test2'}] how can I acheive this?

Comment: i answer a similar question here just now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469803/how-should-i-store-an-array-in-redis/58501945#58501945 . You can use a list to store all the keys name of item keys and hash for each item